# Difference between Pareto optimal redistribution and strict pareto optimal redistribution

Tags: economics, nash-equilibrium, utility

Can someone explain the difference between Pareto optimal redistribution and strict pareto optimal redistribution? Because I know the definition but I do not understand it.

Comment: This is an economics question rather than mathematics, so you should look at the definitions, but I believe that that there is a Pareto improvement if at least one person is better-off and nobody else is worse off, and a strong Pareto improvement if every person is better off

Comment: If you know the definitions, can you please state them here?